# Linq join and project from nested elements

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this existing linq statement:

```
IEnumerable<string> queries = LandingSilo.Relationships
    .Where(x => x.Type == 1 && x.RootKey == root.Key)
    .Join(
        nodes,
        r => r.NodeKey,
        n => n.Key,
        (r, n) => n.Queries.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Seq == r.QueryId))
    .Where(q => q != null)
    .Select(q => q.Query);
```

This query doesn't quite do what I need it to do. It only exposes variables from 'n.Queries', whereas I need to access another variable from 'n' itself, further up the tree.

Required: **n.Url** and **q.Query** - output as a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`.

As you can see, the query links two lists - **LandingSilo.Relationships** and a list represented by the variable **nodes**.

**Nodes** also has a nested list property which contains one of the keys needed to join the lists together, here are the keys:

- LandingSilo.Relationships: NodeKey, QueryId
- nodes: Key, Queries.Seq (Queries is the list inside nodes)

Here are the specs:

LandingSilo.Relationships: `List<SiloRelationship>();`

```
public class SiloRelationship
{
    public SiloRelationship(int type, string rootKey, string nodeKey, int queryId)
    {
        Type = type;
        RootKey = rootKey;
        NodeKey = nodeKey; // Key 1
        QueryId = queryId;  // Key 2
    }

    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string RootKey { get; set; }
    public string NodeKey { get; set; }
    public int QueryId { get; set; }
}
```

nodes: `List<SiloNode>();`

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; private set; } // Key 1
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    public List<NodeQuery> Queries { get; private set; }
}

public class NodeQuery
{
    public string Query { get; private set; }
    public int Seq { get; private set; } // Key 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intermediate anonymous projections to provide access to the other objects from the query, but it leads to quite unreadable code.

For queries involving joins the LINQ query syntax is much more appropriate due to transparent identifier access. Rewriting your query with query syntax could be like this:

```
var query =
    from r in relationships
    where r.Type == 1 && r.RootKey == root.Key
    join n in nodes on r.NodeKey equals n.Key
    from q in n.Queries
    // Here you have access to r,n and q
    where r.QueryId == q.Seq
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(n.Url, q.Query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to select the values as the result of the join as a KeyValuePair

```
IEnumerable<string> queries = LandingSilo.Relationships
.Where(x => x.Type == 1 && x.RootKey == root.Key)
.Join(
    nodes,
    r => r.NodeKey,
    n => n.Key,
    (r, n) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(n.Url, n.Queries.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Seq == r.QueryId)?.Query))
.Where(q => q.Value != null);
```

Comment: This answer works and I have upvoted it. I haven't chosen it as the answer purely because, I found the query syntax below much simpler to understand for my basic level of knowledge.